# Ideal background video size Magento 2

Tags: magento2, video

mayb I am at the wrong place but I wanted to ask you experts out there, in what resolution, maximum size, bitrate and frames per second you would add a background video to a Magento 2 page as a header?

I have tried some versions but I am not sure what would be best.

Yours